# Can't find the bug in my 'writing a file' program

Tags: c, file-writing

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main()

    {

        char file_name[100];
        char insert[100];

        printf("Enter the file name:");
        scanf("%s", file_name);
        FILE *f = fopen((strcat(file_name, ".txt")), "a");
        printf("Insert:");
        scanf ("%[^\n]%*s", insert);
        fprintf(f, "%s", insert);

    }
```

The above stated code is supposed to write/insert data to the file, however, the program is terminating right after printing 'Insert:'. I cant seem to find the problem here.

Comment: Why prompt for a file name?  Can you imagine if `grep` worked that way?  Use command line args: it greatly simplifies your program!

Comment: You're also missing an fclose() at the end. That may be OK, because it might get closed automatically as the program terminates, but in normal use you might not get a small amount of output written until you flush or close because it'll be buffered.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Learn how to **use the debugger** (`gdb`). Read documentation of every function you are using, e.g. [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). Always use the return item count of `scanf` and check for failure (`scanf`, `fopen`, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `scanf`:

```
scanf("%s", file_name);
```

will not consume the newline which you press after entering the file name. It stays in the standard input stream(`stdin`). The `scanf`:

```
scanf ("%[^\n]%*s", insert);
```

scans everything until a newline character, and then scans and discards a string. **`%[^\n]` will fail if the next character is `\n`**. So, `scanf`, in your case fails and returns as the next character is `\n`. `insert` remains uninitialized and contains garbage.

```
fprintf(f, "%s", insert);
```

writes the garbage into `f`.

---

How to fix the problem? Two ways of fixing the issue:

1. Use a `getchar();` just after the first `scanf` to get rid of the newline character left over by the first `scanf`.
2. Use

   ```
   scanf (" %[^\n]%*s", insert);
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   scanf ("%[^\n]%*s", insert);
   ```

   The space before `%[^\n]` scans and discards all [whitespace characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Programming_languages)(like `\n`, space etc),if any, until the first non-whitespace character as seen in the quote of the C11 standard below:

   > **7.21.6.2 The fscanf function**
   >
   > [...]
   >
   > 5. A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can be read. The directive never fails

I prefer the second solution as it takes care of *any* number of whitespace characters.

---

Both these solutions work, but then you have another problem. Your program doesn't stop scanning after you give data for the second `scanf`! Fixing this is easy. Just remove the `%*s` from the second `scanf`.

Wondering why? Quoting the C11 standard,

> **7.21.6.2 The fscanf function**
>
> [...]
>
> 12. The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
>       [...]
>       s  Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters. <sup>286</sup>
>       [...]

So, `%s` will skip leading whitespace characters and will stop scanning when it encounters a whitespace character or, if the length field is present, until the specified length or **until a whitespace character**, whichever occurs first. The bolded part explains it.

---

For improving security, limit the number of characters that `scanf` reads for `insert` and `file_name` so that you can avoid [buffer overflows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). Also, check the return values of both the `scanf`s and `fopen` to see if they were successful. Both the `scanf`s, in your case, returns 1 if successful. If not 1, an error occured. `fopen`, returns `NULL` on failure. If not `NULL`, `fopen` is successful.

---

Final program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()        
{        
    char file_name[100];
    char insert[100];

    printf("Enter the file name:");
    if(scanf("%94s", file_name) != 1)  //Scans a maximum of 94 chars,+1 for \0 at the end,+4 for ".txt"
    {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        exit(-1); //Exit the program with a negative return value
    }

    strcat(file_name, ".txt"); //Improves readability,do one thing in one line 
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "a");

    if(f == NULL) //if fopen failed to open the filename,
    {
        printf("fopen failed\n");
        exit(-1); 
    }

    printf("Insert:");
    if(scanf (" %99[^\n]", insert) != 1) // Note the space before %[^\n],99 scans a maximum of 99 chars,+1 for the \0 at the end
    {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        fclose(f); //Free resources before exiting
        exit(-1);
    }
    fprintf(f, "%s", insert);
    fclose(f); //Close the file after use
}
```

---

If you want to discard the newline character left over by the second `scanf`, use

```
scanf (" %99[^\n]%*c", insert)
```

instead of

```
scanf (" %99[^\n]", insert)
```

It doesn't make a difference in this program, though.

---

If you are wondering why I'm stating quotes from chapter "*7.21.6.2 The fscanf function*" it is because, `fscanf` is exactly the same as `scanf` when the first argument of it is `stdin`. Quoting once again from the C11 standard,

> **7.21.6.4 The scanf function**
>
> [...]
>
> 2. The `scanf` function is equivalent to `fscanf` with the argument `stdin` interposed before the arguments to `scanf`.

Comment: Not my downvote. No idea why you've been downvoted. PS: I've reached my daily limit on voting

Comment: @diplodocus , Seems like the score is now balanced! :)  (2 upvotes,2 downvotes)

Comment: @diplodocus A minimum of research and debugging would have shown you the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is in your first `scanf`.  The carriage return is not being dealt with, which means that the next `scanf` deals with it immediately upon being called since it's still in the buffer.

Perhaps try, `scanf("%s\n", filename);`

Comment: I did that, but now its giving me a new line to enter the input (lets say I enter 'x') and upon moving to the next line it prints 'insert:' and asks for input again (lets say I enter 'y'), and in the end the file is edited with the text 'x'?